What does the phrase "知らんぷって" mean?
In the song Liar Dance by DECO*27, one of the lyrics is:

知らんぷって　今日を重ねるの

I know that 知らん is a more colloquial way of saying 知らない, but I can't figure out what the ぷって part of the text means. I've tried looking in a japanese dictionary, but to no avail. I know that 今日を重ねるの means something like Repeat the days.
Someone please explain what the heck 知らんぷって means, because I can't figure it out.

Maybe it's 知らないぶって (pretending to not know)

This appears to be the te-form of 知らんぷる, which is an imaginary verb back-formed from 知らんぷり.
There is a noun 知らんぷり, which by itself is a fairly common word. ぷり is from 振り. While 知らんぷり may look like a nominalized verb based on this rule, in reality, there is no such godan verb as 知らんぷる. However, the lyricist temporarily assumed the existence of such a word, and conjugated this imaginary godan verb to the te-form.
This is a creative wordplay rather than a standard use of Japanese; the correct (but uninteresting) expression is 知らんぷりをして or 知らない振りをして. Meaning-wise, this 知らんぷって is supposed to mean "I pretended not to know it" or "I ignored it" (or maybe "I dontknowified", or "I unawareized", if these work as jokes at all). だいじょばない (nai-form of the imaginary verb だいじょぶ) is another example similar to this.
